# DateTime comparison PHP

Tags: php, datetime, date-comparison

The second block should execute but neither do. Now I'm adding another sentence so stack will let me make this edit.

```
  <?php

  $earlier_time = new DateTime('2018-12-16 11:17:30');
  $thirty_seconds_later = $earlier_time->add(new DateInterval('PT' . 30 . 'S'));

  if ($thirty_seconds_later < $earlier_time) {
    echo "left is less than right";
  } else if ($thirty_seconds_later > $earlier_time) {
    echo "left is greater than right";
  }

  ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because when you use `DateTime()` it is not immutable so when you call `DateTime::add()` you change the `$earlier_time` object and your comparison will always be equal (you are comparing the same object). Use `DateTimeImmutable()` to solve this problem.

```
<?php
$earlier_time = new DateTimeImmutable('2018-12-16 11:17:30');

$thirty_seconds_later = $earlier_time->add(new DateInterval('PT' . 30 . 'S'));

if ($thirty_seconds_later < $earlier_time) {
    echo "left is less than right";
} else if ($thirty_seconds_later > $earlier_time) {
    echo "left is greater than right";
}
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/1070142)

Comment: Haa, Hi John. Looks like we both had the same idea here :)

Comment: Hmmm. Seems to load okay for me. Are you getting an error or something? I can always mover it over to https://3v4l.org/ if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have added 30 seconds to `$earlier_time` in this line

```
$thirty_seconds_later = $earlier_time->add(new DateInterval('PT' . 30 . 'S'));
```

So instead make your original datetime object immutable and it will not change its value when you do the `->add` but will set the new value into `thirty_seconds_later`

```
$earlier_time = new DateTimeImmutable('2018-12-16 11:17:30');

$thirty_seconds_later = $earlier_time->add(new DateInterval('PT' . 30 . 'S'));


if ($thirty_seconds_later < $earlier_time) {
    echo "left is less than right";
} else if ($thirty_seconds_later > $earlier_time) {
    echo "left is greater than right";
}

?>
```